# Generic triangular numbers sequence formula

Tags: algorithm, math

I know that I can get the nth element of the following sequence

```
1   3   6  10  15  21
```

With the formula

```
(n * (n + 1)) / 2
```

where `n` is the nth number I want. How can I generalise the formula to get the nth element of the following sequences where by following sequences I mean

```
1 -> 1   3   6   10  15  21
2 -> 2   5   9   14  20
3 -> 4   8   13  19
4 -> 7   12  18
5 -> 11  17
6 -> 16
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about practical computer programming but rather belongs on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) once the questioner has added more of his own work and explained just where he is stuck. The question is also unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what do you mean by n-th element in 2D-table (potentially infinite)

Simple formula for element at row and column (numbered from 1):

```
(r+c-1)*(r+c)/2  - (r-1)
```

Possible intuition for this formula:

Key moment: element with coordinates `r,c` stands on the diagonal number `d`, where `d = r + c - 1`

There are  `s = d*(d+1)/2` elements in `d` filled diagonals, so the last element of `d`-th diagonal (rightmost top) has value `s`, and element in `r`-th row of the same diagonal is

```
v(r,c) = s-(r-1) = (d)*(d+1)/2 -(r-1) = (r+c-1)*(r+c)/2  - (r-1)
```

Comment: Hello!
I know has been a while, but, where does this formula come from? Is there a name for this?

Comment: @Sebastian Luna I added possible intuition - how I developed this. Last element of diagonal is sum of arithmetic progression, more exact - sum of natural row, these values are called triangular numbers. Don't know about full formula.